# How to calculate this n dimensional integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The integral such as
[image]

It's easy to evaluate the first few items

```
Integrate[x1 (1/(-1+n))^n (1/v1)^(n/(-1+n)) x1^((2-n)/(-1+n)), {x1, 0, v1}]
Integrate[x1 Integrate[(1/(-1+n))^n (1/v1)^(n/(-1+n)) x1^((2-n)/(-1+n)) x2^((2-n)/(-1+n)), {x2, 0, x1}], {x1, 0, v1}]
Integrate[x1 Integrate[Integrate[(1/(-1+n))^n (1/v1)^(n/(-1+n)) x1^((2-n)/(-1+n)) x2^((2-n)/(-1+n)) x3^((2-n)/(-1+n)), {x3, 0, x1}], {x2, 0, x1}], {x1, 0, v1}]
```

but how do I calculate this integral where the number of integrals is aribtrary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your integral is equal to
$$
I = \left( \frac{1}{n-1} \right)^n \nu_1^{-n/(n-1)} \int_0^{\nu_1} \left\{ x_1 x_1^{(2-n)/(n-1)} \left[ \int_0^{x_1} y^{(2-n)/(n-1)} dy \right]^{n-1} \, \right\} dx_1,
$$
which is easy enough to solve for in Mathematica. Note that we must have $n > 1$ for convergence, and things simplify nicely if we assume that $\nu_1 > 0$ as well.

```
subint[x1_, n_] = Integrate[y^((2 - n)/(n - 1)), {y, 0, x1}, Assumptions -> n > 1]
int[ν1_, n_] = Simplify[(1/(n - 1))^n ν1^(-n/(n - 1)) 
                          Integrate[ x1^((2 - n)/(n - 1) + 1) subint[x1, n]^(n - 1), {x1, 0, ν1}],  
                          Assumptions -> {n > 1, ν1 > 0}]

(* ν1/(-1 + 2 n) *)
```